# Database growth monitor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database called `ABCD` of 100 GB in size, which is going to 100% full in next 6 months. I have to inform end users that the database grows completely in next 6 months & place an order for additional storage.

In this scenario what is the DBCC command used to check database growth and analyze the database growth trend? In before of 6 months?

Answer (score 3):

You can monitor the size of individual database files (both log and data files) by using the system catalog view sys.database_files

Below is an example that will create a table and then store the results of this information for each database. You can then output the data to say Excel, to track the growth over the recorded period of time. You could even forecast your rate of growth.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DatabaseFiles') IS NULL
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE DatabaseFiles
        (
            ID              int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
            CreatedDate     datetime not null default getDate(),
            DatabaseID      int not null,
            DatabaseName    varchar(50) not null,
            FileID          int not null,
            FileName        varchar(50) not null,
            SizeInMB        numeric(12,6),
            FilePath        varchar(150) not null,
            FileType        varchar(10) not null
        )

    END

    --Get the current database file size information for each database on the server
    EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 
        'INSERT INTO DatabaseFiles(DatabaseID,DatabaseName,FileID,FileName,SizeInMB,FilePath,FileType)
        SELECT 
            DB_ID(''?''),
            DB_NAME(DB_ID(''?'')),
            file_id,
            name,
            CAST(((SIZE * 8.00)/1024.00) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS SizeInMB,
            physical_name,
            type_desc
        FROM [?].sys.database_files '
```

Comment: @sriakanth: why the fixation on having a DBCC command to do this?  When people are stuck using a specific technology to solve their problem even when pointed to a different (and possibly better) solution, it sounds like homework.  Is that the case here?

Comment: recently in an interview,interviewer asked this question I answered sys.database_files but interviewer wants a DBCC command.

Comment: @sriakanth: Did you ask them what they had in mind, a quick RTFM doesn't show any DBCC command to get database/file information.

Comment: @Richard - Possibly `DBCC SHOWFILESTATS`

Answer (score 0):

[`sys.allocation_units`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189792.aspx):

```
select sum(total_pages)*8192 as size_used_in_bytes from ABCD.sys.allocation_units;
```

Monitor this query. It will report the total size used (allocated) in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want know the size of DB growth in last one month, you can find using it below. Here DATA% refers to the drive:

```
SELECT dbname,
SUM(Growth)/1024 as GrowthinGB 
FROM [DBMonitoring].[dbo].[FileSizeGrowth]
where
physical_name like 'DATA%'
and sampletime > getdate() - 30
and PrevFileSizeMB <> 0
group by dbname
order by dbname desc
```